# MySQL RIGHT JOIN stops working with this AND statement

Tags: mysql

When I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders_chosenoptions
RIGHT JOIN orders ON (orders.ID = orders_chosenoptions.order_id)
WHERE orders.deal_id = 982
AND orders.status = 'new'
```

It gives me 41 rows. Now these rows their orders_chosenoptions.product_id is either 110 or 111

```
SELECT * FROM orders_chosenoptions
RIGHT JOIN orders ON (orders.ID = orders_chosenoptions.order_id)
WHERE orders.deal_id = 982
AND orders.status = 'new'
AND (orders_chosenoptions.product_id = 110 OR orders_chosenoptions.product_id = 111)
```

Gives me 35 rows?! Like it stops the right join somehow?

There is no other rows with product id other than 110 or 110.

Comment: Aren't you missing an AND after 'new'?

Comment: Are you sure all the rows of the first query have `product_id` filled in? Since it's a right join, there can rows with no match from `orders_chosenoptions`, and they will have `product_id` = `NULL`. The second query will filter these rows out.

Comment: Not all rows in the orders_chosenoptions has product_id filled with value, so they have value 0 is this the cause? how can i grab all the rows then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this::

```
SELECT * FROM orders_chosenoptions
RIGHT JOIN orders ON (orders.ID = orders_chosenoptions.order_id)
WHERE orders.deal_id = 982
AND orders.status = 'new' AND
orders_chosenoptions.product_id in (110, 111)
```

Comment: @Karem: and still if doesnt come, then you table orders_chosenoptions is having null values in product column

Comment: Still nothing, you're right that there are 0 value in the product_id column by default, so other rows have the 0 value if theres no product_id assigned... So how can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM orders_chosenoptions
RIGHT JOIN orders
  ON orders.ID = orders_chosenoptions.order_id
  and orders.deal_id = 982
  AND orders.status = 'new' 
where orders_chosenoptions.product_id = 110
   OR orders_chosenoptions.product_id = 111
```